# Switching from Railo to Coldfusion 11

Tags: coldfusion, migration, railo, cfprint

Our server currently is running Railo. I have search the net for a way to move the CFM pointers from Railo to Coldfusion 11. I find hundreds of CF to Railo but nothing back.

Before anyone asks why we are doing this, it's because of the limitations of Railo for what we need, i.e. CFPDF, CFPrint, etc.

The problem is when I turn off Railo, I cannot process .cfm files. I also need to change where the Coldfusion webroot is to our current webroot. I have it all setup in Apache but CF11 is not seeing it.

I am new to CF11 so please help. Thank you!

You guys asked for a little more information, here is my edit:

We are running on Linux, Debian. It's a web server that we will be deploying Digital PDF's with a limited amount of printing to it. I.E., Customer buys 5 copies, so we need to limit their copies to 5 prints. We know said customer could buy just 1 and photo copy it. However, the owner of the site wants to be able to allow this feature.

Comment: Your question doesn't really detail at all what you've actually done to install CF11, nor what happens other than "cannot process .cfm files" which is pretty vague.  If the code is compat, uninstall Railo, install CF11, and put the code back in.  Make sure you remove the old WEB-INF.

Comment: As @BradWood has said, you need to give us more details about what you have done and your setup, e.g. os, web server, servlet engine, etc... you are using. It simply sounds like the handler for .cfm and probably .cfc is missing somewhere along the line.

Comment: Would you not be better off continuing to run your main app on Railo, and proxy the CF-specific stuff to an additional CF server tasks solely to do that work? It would seem a shame to throw the baby out with the bath water as the saying goes. Why penalise the *rest* of your app for some edge-cases? Also, is there no different third-party solution to your PDF-processing requirements than having to run a CF server? Perhaps raising questions about *those* challenges you have might be worthwhile?

Comment: To echo others, you need to give more info to get a worthwhile answer. That said, checkout wkhtmltopdf. It's by far and away better than CF's PDF documentation. We drive a high quality/resolution print business with it. Renders a headless webkit browser basically to render PDFs. Runs CSS like you would expect, even JavaScript. We use it to dynamically scale fonts and linespacing. Food for thought. A

Comment: Also, you might want to check out PDFBox (https://pdfbox.apache.org/index.html) which is an OpenSource Java Library for generating and handling PDF documents.

Comment: wkhtmltopdf is superb - easy to drop into an existing project

Comment: @andrewdixon As for as PDFBox, can I limit the amount of copies that I can allow to print?

Comment: @antony wkhtmltopdf would not work with what we have going on. We already have the PDF's and there are some licensing issues there.

Comment: Thank you all for the replys. I hope my edits can allow you more information into my situation. I was sick all weekend so I am just now able to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all of the information. We have a new server running ColdFusion 11 and CFPDF is working really well.